# How to convert a 3d plot to a 2d plot along z axis?

Tags: plotting

I have some initial functions which are defined as following

```
\[CapitalGamma]2[re_, rp_, \[Theta]_] := 
  norm^2 Exp[-2 ce re^2 - 2 cp rp^2 + 2 cep re rp Cos[\[Theta]] - 
     2 \[Alpha] (re^2 + rp^2 - 2 re rp Cos[\[Theta]])^(1/2)];

intrE[r_, re_] := (
  E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + r \[Beta])) (E^(-((
      2 (me re + mp (-r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/M^2)) - 
     E^(-((2 (me re + mp (r + re))^2 \[Gamma])/M^2))) M^2)/(
  4 mp (me + mp) \[Gamma]);

\[Rho]E[re_?NumericQ] := (2*\[Pi])/re norm^2*
   NIntegrate[r intrE[r, re], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];

intrp[r_, rp_] := (
  E^(-2 r (\[Alpha] + r \[Beta])) (E^(-((
      2 (mp rp + me (-r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/M^2)) - 
     E^(-((2 (mp rp + me (r + rp))^2 \[Gamma])/M^2))) M^2)/(
  4 me (me + mp) \[Gamma]);
\[Rho]P[rp_?NumericQ] := (2*\[Pi])/rp norm^2*
   NIntegrate[r intrp[r, rp], {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
```

where the constants are

```
me = 1;
mp = 50;
M = mp + me;
\[Omega] = 0.01;
ce = 0.000247788912553343870163233548863610519102107399056985349849479\
46703191080354`50.;
cp = 0.245247788912553348136902700735739726656980674963778186330241636\
32977700884275`50.;
cep = -0.0095044221748933124338261642160228245184438900004460783199088\
8420319108035353`49.97345727051035;
{\[Alpha], \[Beta]} = \
{0.98023965221867725983173613713006488978862762451171875`50., 
   0.00014974969686706935865193324186606105286045931279659271240234375\
`50.};
norm = 0.1401011178487864509093944638657517303615038607799045828553364\
4841877565332156`50.;
\[Gamma] = 
  0.25500000000000000444089209850062616169452667236328125`50.;
```

I define the final function

```
\[CapitalGamma]C[re_, 
   rp_, \[Theta]_] := \[CapitalGamma]2[re, 
    rp, \[Theta]] - \[Rho]E[re]*\[Rho]P[rp];
```

and then plot it

```
Plot3D[\[CapitalGamma]C[re, 1, \[Theta]], {re, 0, 10}, {\[Theta], 
  0, \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Now I want to plot `\[CapitalGamma]C[re, 1, \[Theta]]` as a 2d plot along z-axis for example. I don't know how do it. Should I write it as cartesian coordinates, decompose its components and then set x and y values to zero? or set theta to zero here? Any idea?

**Update**

Notice my mean is not a contour plot. As far as I know, the shape of mine should be similar to a sin function as following:
[image]

There is an alternative to write $\Gamma$ using variables `(re,rp,r)`

```
\[CapitalGamma]1[re_, rp_, r_] := 
  norm^2*Exp[-2 \[Alpha] r - 
     2 \[Beta] r^2 - (2 \[Gamma])/
      M^2 (me^2 re^2 + mp^2 rp^2 + me mp (-r^2 + re^2 + rp^2))];
```

where $r=|re-rp|$

and so we have

```
\[CapitalGamma]C1[re_, rp_, 
   r_] := \[CapitalGamma]1[re, rp, r] - \[Rho]E[re]*\[Rho]P[rp];
```

Comment: `ContourPlot` ?

Comment: No, I mean a 2d curve. like typical `plot` command

Comment: Yes, `ContourPlot` is work. `ContourPlot[\[CapitalGamma]C[re, 1, \[Theta]], {re, 0, 10}, {\[Theta],
   0, \[Pi]}, PlotRange -> All, ContourShading -> None]`

Comment: see the update.

Comment: Please label the axes in your update-plot. This should clarify what you 're looking for!

Comment: Thanks, now we have, assuming `rp==1`  ,axeslabels  `Abs[re-1], \[CapitalGamma]C[re, 1, \[Theta]]` ! What happened with `\[Theta]`???

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Please see the update. I'm really confused, however I added all information which I knew.